# Monitor Mininet OpenFLow Traffic in WireShark with RYU Controller

Tags: wireshark, sdn, mininet, ryu

I am using RYU controller for SDN Setup. I want to monitor basic openflow handshake messages but i have failed to do so..

Here are the steps i do after install of mininet, wireshark and ryu.

```
./bin/ryu-manager --verbose ryu/app/simple_switch_13.py
```

step 2: start virtual network

```
sudo mn --top single,3 --man --controller remote --switch ovsk,Protocols=OpenFLow13
```

Now no traffic shows up in my wireshark.. I am using wireshark version 1.12 which has an openflow dissector installed in it.

When i use capture loop it shows the request and reply packets, but i want to see "Feature Request" From ryu controller in wireshark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what i did:

Be sure "openvswitch-testcontroller" is down:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:/tmp$ service --status-all | grep openv
 [ + ]  openvswitch-switch
 [ - ]  openvswitch-testcontroller
```

Run ryu application:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:~/ryu$ pwd
/home/yavuz/ryu
yavuz@ubuntu:~/ryu$ sudo ryu-manager --verbose ryu/app/example_switch_13.py
lzma module is not available
Registered VCS backend: git
Registered VCS backend: hg
Registered VCS backend: svn
Registered VCS backend: bzr
loading app ryu/app/example_switch_13.py
```

Before mininet run tcpdump for lo (not eth0 or like that)

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -w ryu-local.cap
```

Run mininet:

```
yavuz@ubuntu:/tmp$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --controller=remote --mac
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
Connecting to remote controller at 127.0.0.1:6653
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 h3
*** Adding switches:
s1
*** Adding links:
(h1, s1) (h2, s1) (h3, s1)
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 h3
*** Starting controller
c0
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> h1 ping h2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.38 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.228 ms
```

Stop the trace and open it.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In short => you can't.

`Feature request/reply`is part of `openflow` not part of `IP` stack. So, its embedded in the packets of TCP/IP model.